# How to use h-100 in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a sidebar in admin panel. And I try for this sidebar height be 100%, but I did not solve my problem.

```
<html class="h-100">
<head>
    <title>Admin</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body class="h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-md-2 h-100 bg-dark" id="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific? If you add the background-color: red to .h-100 class you'd see that it is set to 100% height.

Comment: Yes I see that it is set to 100% height, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your style sheet

```
#sidebar{
  height:100vh;
}
```

**Full Code**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admin</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 bg-dark" id="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```